# Android Share Intents - Some files won't share

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am having some issues with Android share intents. I am able to succesfully share image files (jpg, png, gifs), but when I try to share any other files (doc, docx, xlsx, ppt), I get errors from the apps saying that there were errors opening the files, but when I try to open them from the file manager, they work fine.

```
var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath, fileName));

string auth = "xamarintestapp.xamarintestapp.fileprovider";
string mimeType = Android.Webkit.MimeTypeMap.Singleton.GetMimeTypeFromExtension(Android.Webkit.MimeTypeMap.GetFileExtensionFromUrl(fileName.ToLower()));
if (mimeType == null)
mimeType = "*/*";
var file = new Java.IO.File(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath, fileName));
Android.Net.Uri intentUri = null;


Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);

intent.SetDataAndType(uri, mimeType);

intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);


Forms.Context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Choose an App"));
```

I have tried checking the MIME type, and they seem to be correct (application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document for doc and docx files). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `file` scheme-based based uri instead of just passing a filesystem-based path.

Note: The `Downloads` directory is a publicly accessible file location on Android so no granting of rights, nor content provider, is needed, but if these files, doc|x  or not, are coming from within your app's sandbox, then you would need to implement a content provider and share a `content://`-based provider uri to Word, Excel and other apps...

Example:

```cs
var fileName = "demo.docx";
var mimeType = MimeTypeMap.Singleton.GetMimeTypeFromExtension(MimeTypeMap.GetFileExtensionFromUrl(fileName)) ?? "*/*";
var downloads = Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
using (var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView))
using (var uri = new Uri.Builder()
                     .Scheme("file")
                     .Authority("localhost")
                     .AppendEncodedPath(downloads.CanonicalPath)
                     .AppendEncodedPath(fileName)
                     .Build())
{
    intent.SetDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
    StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Choose an App"));
}
```

#### Update:

> ....exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()

Compiling against, say Android P/API-28, and using a minSDKVersion but no targetSDKVersion in the manifest (Xamarin calls it "automatic") and this code will work (I have Android P apps using the latest APIs running using the above code but they do not "target" a specific API level at runtime.)

But you are targeting a specific API >= Nougat thus you will have to implement a file provider to "share" even public files and thus provide content://-based uris to the app you are sharing to.

Comment: I get an exception when showing the picker using this code.  `     Android.OS.FileUriExposedException: file://localhost//storage/emulated/0/Download/hi.docx exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri() `

Comment: @user2901453 ahh, yep, I am compiling against Android P/API-28 and using a minSDKVersion but not any targetSDKVersion (Xamarin calls it "automatic"), you are **targeting** a specific API >= Nougat thus you will have to implement a file provider to share even public files and thus provide `content://`-based uris to the app you are sharing to.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I changed my targetSDKVersion to automatic and now it works.

Comment: @user2901453 Glad it worked for you... just remember if you end up needing to share files in your app's sandbox, you will have to implement a FileProvider.... and Google is changing the Play Store requirements so that you will have to target at least the latest API level (minus one) in the future so this will not work in 2019(?... I would have to re-read the release/update requirements to confirm the timelines on the changes)